# scalar multiplication of geodesic distance

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $d_g(x,y)$ denote the geodesic distance between two points $x,y\in M$ where $(M,g)$ is a Riemannian manifold. Then is $d_g(\lambda x,\lambda y)=\lambda d_g(x,y)$ for all $x,y\in M$ and $\lambda>0$?

Formally it is known that $$d_g(x,y)=\inf \{L(\gamma):\gamma \ \text{is a geodesic such that }\gamma(0)=x,\gamma(1)=y \}$$ where $$L(\gamma)=\int_0^1\sqrt{g_{ij}\frac{dx^i}{dt}\frac{dx^j}{dt}}\,dt$$ Afterwards I am not sure how to verify this one, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your manifold would need to have a scalar multiplication defined on it, in order for the point $(\lambda x, \lambda y)$ to be defined. Also some properties of that scalar multiplication would need to hold.

Comment: Should the condition to be verified read$$d_{\lambda g}(x, y) = \lambda\, d_{g}(x, y)\ \dots$$(which is not how it reads at the moment)?